# Having trouble connecting client to server with IPv6 addresses (echoclient/echoserver pair)

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, getaddrinfo

I'm programming an echoclient/server pair, with the goal of being IP agnostic/accepting IPv4 and IPv6. The intention is to send a message from my client to my server and have the server relay the message. I've followed Beej's guide pretty closely and deviated where necessary, but no matter what I do, I can't get it to work with an IPv6 address. Here is the relevant part of my client code:

```
    char buffer[16];
    int return_value;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); // Initialize contents of hints to 0
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // Allow both IPv4 and IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Stream socket for TCP

    if ((return_value = getaddrinfo(hostname, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(return_value));
        return 1;
        }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }
```

I've tried changing `ai_family` to only IPv6, but that didn't make a difference. I'm getting an output of "client: connect: Cannot assign requested address
client: failed to connect".

Comment: Does your machine have an interface with an IPv6 address?

Comment: I'm using a virtual machine which does.

Comment: What are `hostname` and `PORT` set to?  FWIW I am able to make the posted code connect, if I have a program accepting TCP connections on port 9999 and I put `const char * hostname = "localhost"; const char * PORT = "9999";` in the code.

Comment: when hostname is set to "localhost", and port is set to #define PORT "37482", it works fine. The issue is when I'm testing it with ./echoclient -s 2001:4860:4860::8888 from the command line, which replaces the "localhost" address with the -s one.

Comment: Resolved. Turns out it was the way I was handling the port number in getaddrinfo. I was using a global value of PORT, but I reset it to an array that was converting the port passed in at the CLI using sprintf.